# Why SQL simple float is printed in PHP as long float?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, floating-point

I've a value like "13.4" in a MySQL Database. 
When I print it in a PHP page, it's showed as "13.39999961853"

Any suggestion?

Comment: check `php sprinf` function.

Comment: because it's a float

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty
But with sprintf() function, a value "14" will be displayed as "14.000000". I would like to represent it only as "14", if it haven't decimal part... Any ideas?

Comment: You can always set the precision on that function like `%2f`